# Install vue-cli Globally or Locally

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nodes

When I install @vue/cli globally, I am forced to use sudo in order to initiate a new project, otherwise I receive a permission denied error on the node_modules folder, which contains vue-cli. However, if I use sudo in order to initiate the project, I will require these permissions for any tasks in the future. Should vue-cli be instaled only locally?

Comment: You should use sudo to install @vue/cli globaly, but then you should be able to run the cli as a normal user to create a new project. At least, that is on my Ubuntu machine.

Comment: you shouldn't ever use sudo to install packages (there is also such a thing as postinstall bash scripts, a hacked package could intentionally bork your system), all your doing is installing them into roots your not making it globally accessible to all users. The fix is to fix the permissions on the node_modules folder you mention with chown so is owned by your user.

Comment: Thank you @Daantje. Yes Indeed, this is how it is supposed to work and this is how it is actually working. My apologies, the permission issue was on another directory and not the node-modules one. I had misread the error message. Everything has been fixed and working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

All external libraries/modules which come as part of a language or project should only be installed locally. This includes packages from `npm`, `pypi` and so on. Providing super user access to these libraries is frowned upon and is never a good idea. Otherwise you'd have to review the installation scripts, like say `package.json` before actually installing/updating it globally.

In my personal opinion, you should just install `@vue/cli` in your `home` or `$HOME`, and export the binaries from node modules `bin` folder to access it globally without providing a sudo password. Avoid the `-g` flag while installing.

Another alternate method, if you just want to test `@vue/cli`, is to create a project in your home folder, just meant for testing and add `@vue/cli` and all of the tooling to the `devDependencies` of the project's `package.json` file. You could even export the binaries from this projects node modules and access it globally.

Comment: @JF0001 Glad to have helped. The above $HOME would totally depend on how you have setup your system. Please keep that in mind.